# Jquery script not running on Django paginated pages

Tags: jquery, django, pagination

I have looked all around and tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work.

Problem:
There's a jQuery script that runs perfectly on first page but does not run on any other paginated pages. I had same problem with context variables but I solved it by adding those variables in context processors but I have no idea to solve this problem when it comes to jQuery.

Pagination jQuery:

```
<script>
function ajax_get_update()
{
   $.get(url, function(data){
      var span = $("span.step-links", data);
      $('.blog-home').html(data);
      $('.step-links').html(span);
    }, "html");
}

$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '.step-links #prev' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($( '.step-links #prev' )[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();
    });

    $( '.step-links #next' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($( '.step-links #next' )[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();

    });
});

$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    $( '.step-links #prev' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($( '.step-links #prev' )[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();
    });
    $( '.step-links #next' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($( '.step-links #next' )[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();
    });
});
```

when I remove `.ajaxStop` function jQuery becomes visible to the paginated page but then pagination itself becomes faulty because it doesn't take me beyound second page.

jQuery that I want to run on every paginated page:

```
$(document).ready(function delete_blog(){
$("a[name^='delete-blog']").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //alert($(this).attr('href'));
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken":"{{csrf_token}}"
            },

        success: function(response){

            window.location.href = "some url";
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    });
});
```

});

Is there any workaround? Please let me know if you need more information.
And please do reply :P Nobody replied on my last question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639390/django-pagination-context-variables-are-lost-in-pages-other-than-first-page but nevermind may be it was a stupid question or may be this one is too but please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind handlers in another way. Object, to which you are linking `.on` or `.click` handlers, is being computed only once, on page load (that's why you need `ajaxStop`). If you connect them to the `document` (or other static, non-changeable element), they will work beautifully:

```
$(document).on("click", "#prev", function(event){});
$(document).on("click", "#next", function(event){});
$(document).on("click", "a[name^='delete-blog']", function(event){});
```

P.S. Don't use `.class #id` selectors, they are very slow. `#OnlyID` is way better.

Comment: That is awesome, thanks for making me aware and solving my problem and most of all, replying back! :p